# Soundtransform is not working I think

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

```
I am trying to lower the volume of this sound since it's like a background music track but it's sounding the same why is it and how can I fix it?

var morning:Morning1 = new Morning1();
var morningChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel ();
var transforming:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.1);
morningChannel = morning.play ();
morningChannel.soundTransform = transforming;
```

this is how it really should be

FINAL WORKING:

```
var morning:Sound =new Morning1 ();
//telling the sound to lower
var transforming:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.05);
var morningChannel:SoundChannel = morning.play(0,1,transforming);
```

Comment: By toning it down, did you mean lowering its volume?

Comment: umm yah lool sorry for my bad language...I should change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var morning:Sound =new Morning1 ();
//telling the sound to lower
var transforming:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.05);
var morningChannel:SoundChannel = morning.play(0,1,transforming);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the volume of the sound, you replace the third line with this:

```
var transforming:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform;
transforming.volume = 0.1;
```

Oh, and you have to have it so that the sound plays after you change its properties, so move `morningChannel = morning.play ();` to the end.

Comment: @tailedmouse It's what I do ;)

Comment: umm though its still not working wait i will upload the new code

Comment: @tailedmouse Change `var morning:Morning1 = new Morning1()` to `var morning:Sound = new Morning1()`

Comment: @tailedmouse Try following this format (at the end of the page): http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=13993#p70988

Comment: still nothing is working this is so weird ...I will update the code

Comment: @tailedmouse This might be stupid, but I think I was wrong about moving `morningChannel = morning.play ();`. Put it after the second line.

Comment: umm I need this more than just lowering volume purposes.. so i will eventually have to learn this so might as well learn it now..

Comment: @tailedmouse Thought so. You can always link me the .zip and I can check it out tomorrow.

Comment: loool that's fine u already helped me enough, I will jsut play around with it ;p thx a lot for the help today...

Comment: @tailedmouse Glad to see that you got it working. Again, do remember to close the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the transformation before you play the sound =)
morning.play should be the last line.